# using xjc (jaxb) on xsd like web-app_2_5.xsd doesn't create useable mappings

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, xmlbeans, jibx

### using xjc (jaxb) on xsd like web-app_2_5.xsd doesn't create useable mappings

there is no @XmlAccessorType and no way to Marshall and UnMarshall XML using the mappings. What can be done to modify these mappings  to create useable files? (the ant,maven,xjc command line all give same output)

here is the WebAppType generated for example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "web-appType", propOrder = {
    "descriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon"
})
public class WebAppType {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "resource-env-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "post-construct", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "icon", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "error-page", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "jsp-config", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "message-destination", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "display-name", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "security-constraint", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "message-destination-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "security-role", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "pre-destroy", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "filter", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "env-entry", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ejb-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "filter-mapping", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "mime-mapping", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "distributable", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "persistence-unit-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "login-config", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "servlet", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ejb-local-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "description", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "service-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "persistence-context-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "context-param", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "resource-ref", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "session-config", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "locale-encoding-mapping-list", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "servlet-mapping", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "welcome-file-list", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "listener", namespace = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<?>> descriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "version", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected java.lang.String version;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected java.lang.String id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "metadata-complete")
    protected Boolean metadataComplete;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the descriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon property.
     *
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the descriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon property.
     *
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getDescriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     *
     *
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ResourceEnvRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LifecycleCallbackType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link IconType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ErrorPageType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link JspConfigType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link MessageDestinationType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link DisplayNameType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link SecurityConstraintType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link MessageDestinationRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link SecurityRoleType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LifecycleCallbackType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link FilterType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EnvEntryType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EjbRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link FilterMappingType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link MimeMappingType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EmptyType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PersistenceUnitRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LoginConfigType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ServletType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EjbLocalRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link DescriptionType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ServiceRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PersistenceContextRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ParamValueType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ResourceRefType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link SessionConfigType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ServletMappingType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LocaleEncodingMappingListType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link WelcomeFileListType }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ListenerType }{@code >}
     *
     *
     */
    public List<JAXBElement<?>> getDescriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon() {
        if (descriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon == null) {
            descriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<?>>();
        }
        return this.descriptionAndDisplayNameAndIcon;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the version property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *
     */
    public java.lang.String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the version property.
     *
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *
     */
    public void setVersion(java.lang.String value) {
        this.version = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *
     */
    public java.lang.String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the id property.
     *
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *
     */
    public void setId(java.lang.String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the metadataComplete property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *
     */
    public Boolean isMetadataComplete() {
        return metadataComplete;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the metadataComplete property.
     *
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *
     */
    public void setMetadataComplete(Boolean value) {
        this.metadataComplete = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will create useable mappings form any XML schema (including web-app_2_5.xsd).

You will need to create your `JAXBContext` on a colon (`:`) delimited list of all the generated package names:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.example.foo:com.example.bar")
```

Then you will be able to convert the XML to Java objects (unmarshal) by doing the following:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
```

Then you can write the objects back to XML (marshal) by doing:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is I would have to do it to all the sub sections of the web.xml from web-app_2_5.xml then glue them together with string builder type class thus making JAXB in this instance not much easier to use than other methods. When the XSD parses just fine or you create the schema from JAXB it works great and reduces development time

Comment: @user1889665 - Why do you feel you would need to do it that way?

Comment: there is no way to unmarshal the class from any valid web.xml using jaxb and this xsd. This xsd it doesn't work in xmlbeans either. However, once you remove the <annotation> and <documentation> tags which jibx doesn't support (throws errors), jibx does create java classes that can create web.xml properly. For jaxb and xmlbeans you can construct the xml using really cumbersome code but you can not parse any xml for this XSD

Comment: @user1889665 - I'm not sure what you mean.  It appears as though you have successfully generated the model (you posted one class in your question).  What code have you tried to do the unmarshal?

Comment: old issue, but to sum it up jaxb and xmlbeans didn't create proper code from web.xml due to some annotation and documentation tags which jibx did handle properly. Good idea to grep your xml files for these tags before running jaxb or xmlbeans to avoid issues

Comment: @user18896654353 - Can you post an example of one that caused a problem?